# will polynomial interpolation give a polynomial satisfying those points only

Tags: interpolation

when you derive an interpolating polynomial say through 3 points is there a chance for that polynomial to satisfy any other point other than those 3 points? (Any other point in the same domain)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Try using mathjax to make you question more presentable.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Think, for example, of interpolating three points on a parabola with a second-order polynomial.

Comment: Then is there any other way to express a relationship between those 3 points which is not satisfied by any other point?

Comment: There's the obvious solution of specifyingthe set of those three points, e.g., $\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)\}$.  But I suspect there are some additional conditions that you have in mind.